# Pycharm - coverage in mako templates

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, coverage.py, python-coverage

I've got tests to cover 100% of my Python code. Beside it my code fails on TypeError in mako template.
Is it any way to make pycharm's coverage show code coverage in templates too?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coverage-mako-plugin/src)?